# Is there an automated way to split a comic book into its panels (frames)?

Tags: pdf, image-processing

I am looking for such a piece of software running under Linux or Windows.

The **input format** of the files do not really matter (I'll convert my files accordingly): pdf, cbr, cbz, images, epub, ...

But for the **output format**, it should be numbered images (or cbr, cbz, ... -- these are anyway nothing more than numbered image inside a zip). 
I could be happy with other formats as well, but there would be no sense to get a pdf as an output...

Answer (score 1):

A few weeks ago I stumbled on your/this question. Having some time on my hands and finding it an interesting technical challenge I decided giving it a try myself.

It resulted in the repository https://github.com/thieupepijn/ComicPanelSplitter

This repository contains, apart from the source code, also a binary for Windows (under release). Hope this program is what you are looking for.

Comment: @johannes ddi you try this? Any feedback?